# How can i combine these two queries using join on the same table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MAX(property_price) AS LargestSalePrice
     , MIN(property_price) AS LowestSalePrice 
  FROM property_listings 
 WHERE property_intent = 'Sale' 

SELECT MAX(property_price) AS LargestRentPrice
     , MIN(property_price) AS LowestRentPrice 
  FROM property_listings 
 WHERE property_intent = 'Rent'
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want your output to look like?

Comment: A table schema would be nice too for queries.  I guess at the point where that's not asking a lot, you don't need help with your queries anymore :P

Comment: CREATE TABLE `property_listings` (
  `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `property_price` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `property_intent` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `property_listings` (`property_id`, `property_price`, `property_intent`) VALUES
(2, '45345346.00', 'Sale'),
(4, '56236666.00', 'Sale'),
(5, '9898999.00', 'Rent'),
(6, '780000.00', 'Rent'),
(8, '560000090.00', 'Sale'),
(35, '123.00', 'Sale'),
(40, '4536456.00', 'Sale'),
(41, '562369.00', 'Rent'),
(43, '89000000.00', 'Sale'),
(62, '5892323.00', 'Sale');

Comment: very nice.  sql fiddle is even better! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a0cd4/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT MAX(property_price) AS LargestSalePrice, MIN(property_price) AS LowestSalePrice 
      FROM property_listings WHERE property_intent = 'Sale') as Sale,
     (SELECT MAX(property_price) AS LargestRentPrice, MIN(property_price) AS LowestRentPrice 
      FROM property_listings WHERE property_intent = 'Rent') as Rent
```

Comment: It does answer the question, I'll grant you that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this.

```
SELECT MAX(property_price) as MaxPrice, 
 MIN(property_price) as MinPrice, 
 property_intent 
FROM property_listings
WHERE property_intent IN('Rent','Sale')
GROUP BY property_intent;
```

It changes your output, but for the better, as there's no need to hard code different result field names for the min and max prices.  This uses SQL more as it was intended - the result includes `property_intent` so when you handle the results, you know which is which and can further look up from there.  And when you want to add the other `property_intent` values, you just drop the `WHERE` and get a full report.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a0cd4/1

Comment: By the way, look at how I did that SQL fiddle.  If you have SQL questions, and you include a fiddle, answer quality will skyrocket.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. But I really must maintain my output since I will use the outputted figures (LargestSalePrice, LowestSalePrice , LargestRentPrice and LowestRentPrice) elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work:

```
SELECT MAX(property_price) AS LargestSalePrice, MIN(property_price) AS LowestSalePrice FROM property_listings WHERE property_intent = 'Sale'

UNION

SELECT MAX(property_price) AS LargestRentPrice, MIN(property_price) AS LowestRentPrice FROM property_listings WHERE property_intent = 'Rent'
```

Comment: Except for the obvious flaw :-(

Answer (score -1):

First option:

```
SELECT 
     property_intent,  
     MAX(property_price) AS LargestPrice, 
     MIN(property_price) AS LowestPrice 
FROM 
      property_listings 
WHERE  
      property_intent IN ('Sale', 'Rent') 
GROUP BY
      property_intent
```

Second option:

```
SELECT 
     'Sale' AS property_intent, 
     MAX(property_price) AS LargestPrice, 
     MIN(property_price) AS LowestPrice 
FROM 
     property_listings 
WHERE 
     property_intent = 'Sale'
UNION
SELECT 
     'Rent' AS property_intent, 
     MAX(property_price) AS LargestPrice, 
     MIN(property_price) AS LowestPrice 
FROM 
     property_listings 
WHERE 
     property_intent = 'Rent'
```